# Why aren't my assets recognised by symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

```
php bin/console assets:install --env=prod --symlink --relative
```

My bundle is not in the generated list. There are other bundles in there.

The bundle is installed in vendors (from private vcs), registered in symfony, file structure

```
Resources
----public
    ----js
        main.js
    ----css
        main.css
----assets
```

etc...

The bundle class is empty, but I don't think that is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The bundle class `WhateverBundle.php` needs to be in the same directory as `Resources`

Comment: No sure to understand what you mean with "same directory as the Resource directory"